# Is it possible in visNetwork to use the options code generated by visConfigure to create a new network?

Tags: r, shiny, visnetwork

I'm creating a Shiny app that allows the user to edit a *visNetwork* network using the `manipulation = TRUE` option in *visOptions*.

I noticed that there is an option in *visConfigure* to set `initiallyActive = TRUE`, but cannot figure out how to enable this option by default on my graph.